# PrimeNg p-column apply css in a td not working

Tags: css, angular, html-table, primeng

I'm using a p-dataTable and I'd like to apply a style in a td but this style depends on a field's value and I don't know how do it. My code is:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" resizableColumns="true" [responsive]="true" reorderableColumns="true">
  <p-column [styleClass]="carStyle" field="carDesc"></p-column>
  <p-column styleClass="ui-model-car" field="carModelDesc"></p-column>
  <p-column styleClass="ui-width-icon-car">
     <template let-col let-item="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="{{item.typeCarDesc}}">
          <span class="icon-circle {{item.typeCarIcon}} {{item.carColor}}"></span>
      </div>
     </template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

carStyle could be empty or ui-without-border-top and my css:

```
td.ui-without-border-top {border-top-style: hidden;}
```

In my html generated code I don't see the carStyle. I need the style in the td.

Comment: Please confirm if i understand your question correctly. You want class carStyle added if variable carStyle is not empty. You want class ui-without-border-top added if carStyle is empty?

Comment: I want to add the class 'ui-without-border-top' in a td, variable carStyle is empty or is equal to 'ui-without-border-top' so I wanted to set [styleClass]="carStyle" but the code html doesn't set the value of carStyle, but If I set this variable in a div into the template, the code html sets the value of carStyle  '<p-column styleClass="ui-width-room">
      <template let-col let-item="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
          <div class="{{item.carStyle}}">
              {{item.carDesc}}
          </div>
      </template>
  </p-column>'

Comment: Have you tried the Angular 2 custom selectors for styling component's insides? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors

Comment: I don't know how to use those selectors in this situation because I need to set a style into some td not into all td of the table. 

The problem if I put the css in the column: [styleClass]="carStyle" the code doesn't generate the style, but if I put the class into the div: class="{{item.carStyle}}" the code generates the style, but I need the style in the td not in the div

Answer (score 0):

Please do check if the *carStyle* class has been added to your `<td>` in this case.

I will show how i did this without any issues:

In my template:

```
<p-column styleClass="col-button">
```

And my Scss:

```
table {
    tbody
    {
        td.col-button {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

See below screenshot for how well it worked without issues:
[image]

Please check your code and try again. Please post in a fiddle of your issue if it doesn't work.